# Doctrine Single Table Inheritance

Tags: php, doctrine

Does doctrine support this shema with many generations?
Documentation luck the examples.

```php
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

#[Entity]
#[InheritanceType('SINGLE_TABLE')]
#[DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'discr', type: 'string')]
#[DiscriminatorMap(['female' => Female::class, 'male' => Male::class])]
class Person
{
    // ...
}


class Employee extends Person
{
    // property for employee
}

#[Entity]
class Female extends Employee
{
    // shared property of person and employee
}
#[Entity]
class Male extends Employee
{
    // shared property of person and employee
}
```